# Multiplying fractional exponents

Tags: math, algebra

I'm doing Tim Roughgarden's Algorithms course and he has a slide with an integer multiplication algorithm.

Whats the rule that makes 10<sup>(<sup>n</sup>/<sub>2</sub>)</sup>a * 10<sup>(<sup>n</sup>/<sub>2</sub>)</sup>c become 10<sup>(n)</sup>ac ?

What do you do when multiplying fractional exponents like that?

Comment: That seems like the [product rule](http://www.rapidtables.com/math/number/exponent.htm#product).

Comment: This question seems better suited to [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about math, not programming, and should be asked at [Mathematics Stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: As this is programming, please take care if this is integer division so the exponents stay integer. If so, the identity only holds for even `n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's based on the [First Index Law](http://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/Engineering%20maths%20first%20aid%20kit/latexsource%20and%20diagrams/2_1.pdf), where:

a<sup>m</sup> * a<sup>n</sup> = a<sup>m + n</sup>

in your case, the powers add to give <sup>n</sup>/<sub>2</sub> + <sup>n</sup>/<sub>2</sub> = <sup>2n</sup>/<sub>2</sub> = n

Answer (score 2):

Base is the same so you just add the power of 10 i.e., (<sup>n</sup>/<sub>2</sub>) + (<sup>n</sup>/<sub>2</sub>) = n. Then it's basic multiplication 10<sup>(n)</sup>*a*c= 10<sup>(n)</sup>ac.